# Dagger2 - "is not a framework type." error

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying to use the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` to provide a class in my dagger module and I'm seeing the error: `[ClassName] is not a framework type.`

Does anyone know what a "framework type" is and in which cases would a class not be one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at [the documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.13/dagger/android/ContributesAndroidInjector.html) it says that

> This annotation must be applied to an abstract method in a Module that returns a concrete Android framework type (e.g. FooActivity, BarFragment, MyService, etc).

You can use it with fragments, activities, services, or applications. You can **not** use it to create arbitrary modules with arbitrary objects. You should use constructor injection where possible, and `@Provides` annotated methods where not.

Field injection is reserved for (Android) framework types and should not be used if you can provide your objects in the 2 ways mentioned above.

I would suggest that you have another look at the Dagger 2 documentation or some tutorials for further information on how you can provide objects. You can also find a blog post of myself about [the Dagger Basics](https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2016/05/04/dagger-2-introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

In my case the error occurred when using dagger **2.20**.
The issue drove me crazy so I took a clean example and everything was working correctly until I upgraded the version to 2.20. Then I got the "is not a framework type" error.
**I changed the version to 2.19** and everything was working again.

Comment: I had the same issue. I downgraded to *2.19* and it worked. No idea why it is so though

Comment: Same issue here. My guess is that it's related to the jetifier and not using the latest androidx libs (I'm using the gradle plugin 3.2.1, and androidx packages 1.0.0)

Comment: @aviv-mor @ cr05s19xx Just tried updating to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-rc01` and `com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02`, which fixed the problem...

Comment: updating to com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02  doesn't work, I guess it is another root cause for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error occurs when there is a compilation issue in the fragment and somehow dagger compiler runs first and things it's not a fragment (due to the compilation error).

Answer (score 1):

If you have this issue after upgrading to version 2.20 like @aviv-mor, check you have also upgraded `com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor` and `com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler` like that :

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.20'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.20'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, same error appears when I was doing this in the wrong way, declaring twice the NotificationsModule instead of the activity to add:

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = NotificationsModule.class)
    abstract NotificationsModule notificationsModule();
}
```

causing a circular dependency. The right way:

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = NotificationsModule.class)
    abstract NotificationsActivity notificationsActivity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the dependencies as given below:

```
// dagger
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.20'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.20'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.20'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.20'
```